# using object initializer generates CA 2000 warning

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop, object-initializers

Following code generates a CA2000 warning:

```
Myclass myclass = null;
try
{
   myclass = new Myclass { Name = "a name" };
}
finally
{
   if (myclass != null)
   {
      myclass.Dispose();
   }
}
```

i found some topics with the same problem and as I understand the problem is, that the compiler generates for the constructor a temporary variable and for this variable I'm not calling Dispose().

```
var tmp = new MyClass();
tmp.Name = "a name";
myclass = tmp:
```

so my question is, if there is a solution with using object initializer which not generates a ca2000 warning.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: I also wondered why you were manually writing out a `using` statement, but the same warning is generated even there.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409918/object-initializer-and-dispose-when-property-can-throw-exception)

Comment: I saw this topic (and some others with same problem). but in all this topics I didn't found a solution with using object initializers.

Comment: That's because all of the answers boil down to "there's no way to do it, because the way that object initializers are implemented mean that you could leak the `IDisposable` object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Damien points out in the comments, the FxCop warning is valid, since the C# compiler creates the `IDisposable` instance in a hidden `temp` variable, and when an exception is thrown during the initialization of one of the properties that instance will not get disposed.

With a good API design this would not be a problem, since resources (things that implement `IDisposable`) should contain an `Open` (or `Begin`, `Start`, whatever) method (according to the Framework Design Guidelines), and should not leak before `Open` is called. This rule is created for the same reason as what you are experiencing: to prevent leaking during initialization. The FDG were written before C# 3.0, but the same problem exists when the an exception is thrown from within the constructor of that instance (which can always happen because of asynchronous exceptions such as thread aborts). Since the reference to the instance isn't published at that point, there is no way for anyone to dispose that instance. Initializing the underlying resources during construction is therefore not advised.

So you can safely discard that warning when `Myclass` contains some sort of `Open` method, and when you're not initializing it with values that implement `IDisposable` themselves. In other cases, you should revert to the following:

```
var myclass = new MyClass();

try
{
    myclass.Name = "a name";
}
finally
{
    myclass.Dispose();
}
```